# Command not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to check if "sender" has one of two roles required, but the command is not executing. No errors in console, just command doesn't execute.

```js
const revAmount = commandArgs
  .split(/ +/g)
  .find((arg) => !/<@!?\d+>/g.test(arg));
const revTarget = message.mentions.users.first();
const sender = message.author;

if (
  sender === message.member.roles.cache.has('806432940094390273') ||
  sender === message.member.roles.cache.has('806433001843326996')
) {
  if (!revAmount || isNaN(revAmount))
    return message.channel.send(
      `Sorry ${message.author}, that's an invalid amount.`,
    );
  if (revAmount <= 0)
    return message.channel.send(
      `Please enter an amount greater than zero, ${message.author}.`,
    );

  currency.add(revTarget.id, -revAmount);
}
```

Does someone know what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roles.cache` is a collection and their [`has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) method returns a boolean.

When you check if `sender === message.member.roles.cache.has(...)`, you're checking if an object is strictly equal to a boolean. It will always return `false` so anything inside that if statement is ignored.

You can remove `sender ===` and just check if the member `has` the required role:

```js
if (
  message.member.roles.cache.has('806432940094390273') ||
  message.member.roles.cache.has('806433001843326996')
) {
```